# Footer on First page only with FreeMarker

Tags: templates, pdf, pdf-generation, footer, freemarker

I am using FreeMarker to generate pdfs

I need the footer to only be shown on the first page only no matter how many pages long my content becomes

If I use `#footer {position: running(footer);}`

It is shown on all pages, I do not want that, how can I achieve it only on 1 page

Comment: That looks like CSS. If it is, tag the question with that instead of FreeMarker.

Comment: @ddekany can it be done with CSS , it will still be generated through FreeMarker

Comment: You can use   `?index` if the size is 1 then you can add the content otherwise dont

Comment: @soorapadman not clear

Comment: Are you creating all the pages through ftl?

Comment: As pagination is not done by FreeMarker, it's likely that you have to solve this on the CSS level. Something along the lines of `@page :first { #footer { display: block } }` and then a more generic `#footer { display: none }` that it overrides on the first page. But my CSS is rusty.